# com.elovirta.ooxml v.1.4.0. merged cells from html not being processed correctly

Tags: xslt, plugins, docx, oxygenxml, dita-ot

Dita-ot 3.7.4, com.elovirta.ooxml v.1.4.0 plugin problem with handling merged cells

[conversion example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de6C2.jpg)

The html input is a table with merged cells. The output (docx) is expected to have a similar table.

Ditamap example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "lw-map.dtd">
<map>
    <title>merged cells problem</title>
    <topicref href="hdita/example.html" format="hdita"></topicref>
</map>
```

Table html code example (HDITA topic):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Example_table (hdita)</title>
</head>
<body>
 <article>
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 44.285%;">
   <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 20.0315%;">
    <col style="width: 20.0315%;">
    <col style="width: 20.0315%;">
    <col style="width: 20.0315%;">
    <col style="width: 19.8786%;">
   </colgroup>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="5">A1:A5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>B1</td>
     <td>B2</td>
     <td>B3</td>
     <td>B4</td>
     <td>B5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2">C1:C2</td>
     <td rowspan="2">C3:D3</td>
     <td>C4</td>
     <td>C5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>D1</td>
     <td>D2</td>
     <td>D4</td>
     <td>D5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>E1</td>
     <td>E2</td>
     <td colspan="3">E3:E5</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </article>
</body>
```

Comment: I would consider raising an issue on the tool(s) you use there, unless you have written some custom XSLT you think needs to be fixed; you would need to show that in the question. But I don't quite understand where with a HTML document as the input and wanted .docx output DITA is involved.

Comment: I have a phase.ditamap file and a topic example.html file which has a table in it. With command : {dita --input=phase.ditamap --format=docx} I am converting html to docx. at the same time, the table is distorted, see the link to the figure.Using default plugin without custom xsl